# (Matlab) Exam questions about iteration result

Tags: matlab, iteration, numerical-analysis

I am preparing for a written test in numerical analysis.

There are multiple-answer questions of the type:

**The code below gives a print-out closest to...**

```
N=100;
dt=0.5/N;
x=1;
for n=1: N-1
x=x+dt*x*x;
end
display(x);
```

**Correct option: 2**

---

**The code below gives a print-out closest to...**

```
N=100;
x=1;
y=1;
for n=1: N-1
x = x - (x-exp(-x))/(1+exp(-x));
y = y - (y-exp(-y));
end
display(x-y)
```

**Correct option: 0**

---

**The code below has a print-out that most often will be...**

```
s=0.0;
N=10000;
for n=1:N
x=rand(1);
s=s+3*x*x+x;
end
display(s/N)
```

**Correct option: 1.5**

For the first question I assumed it was some use of Eulers method but I could not arrive at the number 2. I'm not sure how to tackle the second and third one.

Is there some kind of general strategy I can use to figure out what iterations like this should converge towards (without the use of a computer) ?

Answer (score 3):

The general strategy is to look at what the iteration that is being implemented is doing.

**First question**

This is `dx/x^2=dt`, i.e. `1/x0-1/x=t`, i.e. `x=x0/(1-x0*t)=1/(1-1*0.5)=2`.

**Second question**

The equation for `x` is Newton's method for `f(x)=x-exp(-x)`, i.e. `f'(x)=1+exp(-x)`, so the solution is the root of `x=exp(-x)`.

The equation for `y` is fixed point iteration for `y=exp(-y)`. These both have the same solution `x=y=0.5671 (4sf)`.

**Third question**

`rand(1)` is the uniform distribution on [0,1] with mean `1/2` and variance `1/12` so `<x^2>=1/12+1/4=1/3` and `3<x^2>+<x>=3/3+1/2=1.5`.